# How to remove comma from my array value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, matrix

hi pretty new to javascript.I am pretty confused in spliting my array value

```
   console.log(arr)//[ [ [ 10, 0 ] ], [ [ 8, 0 ] ], [ [ 8, 0 ] ], [ [ 5, 2 ] ] ]
    var line = "";

    arr.forEach(e => {

              e.forEach(f => line += "[" + f.join(",") + "],");

    });
console.log(line);//[10,0],[8,0],[8,0],[5,2],
```

But i want my ouptput like this to do matrix addition

```
 console.log(line);//[[10,0],[8,0],[8,0],[5,2]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `map()` for this.

```js
var arr = [ [ [ 10, 0 ] ], [ [ 8, 0 ] ], [ [ 8, 0 ] ], [ [ 5, 2 ] ] ];
var result = arr.map(function(a) {
  return a[0];
});

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Looking at the question it *seems* (though it's not explicit) that the OP may want a String, rather than an Array as the result.

Comment: @DavidThomas The OP wrote: _But i want my ouptput like this:_ `[[10,0],[8,0],[8,0],[5,2]]`

Comment: @K.Daniek: yes, I read the question too. Which is why the use of String concatenation, and `Array.prototype.join(',')`, stood out as the OP *possibly* wants a String rather than an Array. As I said, the question is vague on the subject and both interpretations are valid (certainly so far as I read the question). My comment was, if you want to read it as criticism, intended constructively.

Comment: @DavidThomas Agreed. This is an example what happens if you try to code without knowing fundamentals of the language. Another thing - this is what happens if you don't know how to ASK a question - misleading.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by changing where the join happens and pre/app-ending some square brackets, e.g.

```
var line = arr.map(e => e.map(f => f.join(",")));
console.log('[' + line.join('],[') + ']');

// [10,0],[8,0],[8,0],[5,2]
```

I do have to ask though, why are you getting back a set of arrays each with a single value? Is it possible to avoid getting a dataset like that in the first place? You could avoid the double map/foreach that way.

For instance if you had one level less nesting in your source array the map line would become a little simpler

```
var arr = [ [ 10, 0 ], [ 8, 0 ], [ 8, 0 ], [ 5, 2 ] ]; 
var line = arr.map(f => f.join(","));
console.log('[' + line.join('],[') + ']');
```

This is of course if you want to specifically output the string for the array matrix, if you just wanted a flatter version of your original array then you could do:

```
var newList = arr.map(f => f[0]);
// [ [ 10, 0 ], [ 8, 0 ], [ 8, 0 ], [ 5, 2 ] ]
```